# How can I access each elements in tensor?

Tags: python, arrays, tensorflow, element

Let me assume that I have an tensor like

```
test = tf.constant([1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9])
```

I want to get some value(not row or col) in this tensor.
How can I do this? I want to get (2,3) value which is 6 in here.

Also I want to do this in multi-dimensional array.

'slice' or other tensor functions does not fit for me because I want to deal with multi dimensional array(not only 2x2 but 2x3x4x10  etc..)

please help

Comment: use `test[1,2]` which is 6. Make your test array 2-d, its currently a sequence:`tf.constant([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])`

Comment: It works very well thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you want is [tf.gather](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather) or [tf.gather_nd](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather_nd)